# No unique bean of type [javax.persistence.EntityManagerFactory] is defined: expected single bean but found 0:

Tags: spring, hibernate, jpa-2.0

I am using springframework 3.2 with jboss server 7.1 . 
Trying to set up a simple spring app with jpa2(hibernate provider, mysql) and spring mvc.

I use a simple DAO which i inject with autowired annotation in the home controller.
This dao class simply has a field (em) for persistentContext to get injected, it coudlnt be more trivial, i dont use a persistence.xml since spring from version 3.1 and up does not need one.....note that packages  are scanned properly
i have tried everything from other solutions posted in the web (including here)...
but i get this error:

> org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not
>   autowire field: com.stko.home.model.daos.UserDao
>   com.stko.home.controllers.HomeController.userDao; nested exception is
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error
>   creating bean with name 'userDao': Injection of persistence
>   dependencies failed; nested exception is
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No
>   unique bean of type [javax.persistence.EntityManagerFactory] is
>   defined: expected single bean but found 0: 
>     org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:514)
>     org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:87)
>     org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:285)
>     org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1120)
>     org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:522)
>     org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:461)
>     org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:295)
>     org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:223)
>     org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:292)
>     org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:194)
>     org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:607)
>     org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:932)
>     org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:479)
>     org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:647)
>     org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:598)
>     org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:661)
>     org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:517)
>     org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initServletBean(FrameworkServlet.java:458)
>     org.springframework.web.servlet.HttpServletBean.init(HttpServletBean.java:138)
>     javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:242)
>     org.jboss.as.jpa.interceptor.WebNonTxEmCloserValve.invoke(WebNonTxEmCloserValve.java:50)
>     org.jboss.as.web.security.SecurityContextAssociationValve.invoke(SecurityContextAssociationValve.java:153)
>     org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102)
>     org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:368)
>     org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:877)
>     org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:671)
>     org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:930)
>     java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)

my applicationContext.xml:

```
<bean class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource" destroy-method="close" id="dataSource">
    <property name="driverClassName" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"/>
    <property name="url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/mmydb"/>
    <property name="username" value="user"/>
    <property name="password" value="1234"/>
</bean>

<bean class="org.springframework.dao.annotation.PersistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor" />

<bean id="entityManagerFactory"
        class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean" >

<property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"/>
    <property name="jpaVendorAdapter">
        <bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter"/>
    </property>


    <property name="packagesToScan" value="com.stko.home.model.entities"/>

            <property name="jpaProperties">
                <props>
                    <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5InnoDBDialect</prop>
                    <prop key="hibernate.max_fetch_depth">3</prop>
                    <prop key="hibernate.show.sql">true</prop>
                    <prop key="hibernate.connection.charSet"> UTF-8</prop>
                </props>

            </property>
        </bean>

<!--  tell spring to use annotation based congfigurations -->
<context:annotation-config />

 <!-- scan for beans -->
<context:component-scan base-package="com.stko.home.model.daos"/>

<!-- to recognize persistnce annotations like PersistenceContext -->
<bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.support.PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor"/>
<tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager" />

<bean id="databaseProperties" class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer">
        <property name="location" value="classpath:database.properties"/>
</bean>
```

my servlet-context.xml:

```
<!-- Enables the Spring MVC @Controller programming model -->
<annotation-driven />

<!-- Handles HTTP GET requests for /resources/** by efficiently serving up static resources in the ${webappRoot}/resources directory -->
<resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/resources/" />

<!-- Resolves views selected for rendering by @Controllers to .jsp resources in the /WEB-INF/views directory -->
<beans:bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
    <beans:property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/views/" />
    <beans:property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
</beans:bean>


<context:component-scan base-package="com.stko.home"/>
```

my web.xml:

```
<!-- The definition of the Root Spring Container shared by all Servlets and Filters -->
<context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>/WEB-INF/spring/root-context.xml</param-value>
</context-param>

<!-- Creates the Spring Container shared by all Servlets and Filters -->
<listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
</listener>

<!-- Processes application requests -->
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>appServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>/WEB-INF/spring/appServlet/servlet-context.xml</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>appServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

my userDao:

```
@Service("userDao")
@Repository
public class UserDao implements Serializable {
  @PersistenceContext
  private EntityManager em;

  @Transactional
  public  void saveUser(User user) {
  if(user!=null)
   em.persist(user);
  }

}
```

my entity class User:

```
   @Entity
   @Table(name = "user")
   public class User implements Serializable {

   @Id
   @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
   @Column(name = "userid")
   private Integer userid;

   @Column(name="username")
   private String username;
   public User(){}
   }
```

my typical home controller:

```
@Controller
public class HomeController {
.....

@Autowired
UserDao userDao;

@RequestMapping(value = "/", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String home(Locale locale, Model model) {

.....


User newUser = new User();
newUser.setName("blabla");

userDao.saveUser(newUser);

return "home";
} 

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you have a persistence.xml in which you have defined your persistence unit?

Comment: i did so... i had one such file and also connected the persistence unit name with the EntityManagerFactory with a persistence unit property inside the LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean declaration, in applicationContext.xml. Also tried to use the unit name in the @persistenceContext annotation ... and many more combinations... but spring does not need such a file as it used to...

Answer (score 0):

The issue most likely is this line in `servlet-context.xml` file:

```
<context:component-scan base-package="com.stko.home"/>
```

which is essentially trying to create your DAO once more in your Web application Context. You should just have a filter which only creates your controllers here, this way:

```
<context:component-scan base-package="com.stko.home">
<context:include-filter expression="org.springframework.stereotype.Controller" type="annotation" />
</context:component-scan>
```

Comment: i just tried that but i still get the same error. :( (I use maven for package (always using clean before to avoid surprises) along with jboss admin console for deployment.) It tries to re-create the entityManagerFactory bean or it cant find one? the exception message seams misleading to me, comparing with previous questions in stack.....

Comment: also it says...expected single bean but found 0: zero..?

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
<bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean" id="entityManagerFactory">
    <property name="persistenceUnitName" value="persistenceUnit"/>
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"/>
    <property name="jpaDialect">
        <bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaDialect" />
    </property>
</bean>
```

Define the properties for your EMF bean, persistenceUnit should be the name you declare on persistence.xml